# For Loop with Changing Variable Names

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to create a for loop that performs the same operation with different variable names. For instance; in the below code, I would like to loop the code 6 times, and every instance of the word "civil" would be variable based on values in an array.

```
civilSheet.activate();
  //grab values from column A and determine which rows the Hot List, Coordination Items, and Responsibilities information
  var civilData = civilSheet.getRange('A:A').getValues();
  for(var j=0;j<civilData.length;j++){
    if(civilData[j] == "~Hot List~"){
      var civilHot = j+3;
    } else if(civilData[j] == "~Coordination Items~"){
      var civilCoord = j+1;
    } else if(civilData[j] == "~Responsibilities~"){
      var civilResp = j+1;
    }
  }
```

The goal is something along the lines of the below code:

```
var variableNames = ["civil", "struct", "avl", "fpm", "electrical", "arch"];
  for(var i=0;i<variableNames.length;i++){
    var i+"Data" = i+"Sheet".getRange('A:A').getValues();
    for(var j=0;j<i+"Data".length;j++){
      if(i+"Data"[j] == "~Hot List~"){
        var i+"Hot" = j+3;
      } else if(i+"Data"[j] == "~Coordination Items~"){
        var i+"Coord" = j+1;
      } else if(i+"Data"[j] == "~Responsibilities~"){
        var i+"Resp" = j+1;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: JavaScript does not have dynamic variable names. It does have computed properties, but this is another story. For everyone's sake, why should it matter what the variable name is? Only those who *read* the code see it. What runs your code does not care about how vars are named, only data *held* by the variable is relevant.

Comment: I agree with @Oleg - dynamic variable names are a bad idea. Can you use a dictionary here?  Like `data["civil"][0]` ?

Comment: @Mike67 - hm, seems like the OP does not even need a dictionary, I can't see where the data held by `civilHot`, etc is dependent on the value of `i`. Probably without a data sample, it will remain a mystery.

Comment: The end goal is finding a way of running the code 6 times through a loop in lieu of copying and pasting the same code 6 times with different variable names.

Comment: @ChrisMMgr that much we get. The only question to you - why? Variable names play no role in running the code. Take a look at MDN, it should help you get started: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables

Comment: The "why" is simply because I wanted to be more efficient with code lines (if possible). The above snippet of code is a sample from a longer section.  Everything works fine, I just wanted a more efficient option in 100 lines versus 600.

Comment: @ChrisMMgr - I think you are missing the point here. A script is a set of instructions for the machine to perform based on strict rules. It does not (and cannot) care about variable *naming*. Nor does it care about number of lines you have. If you are struggling with code reuse, take a guide in JavaScript first, for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Looping_code

Comment: @ChrisMMgr Code shortening is a good endeavor. But creating variables is NOT.   What are the variables `["civil", "struct", "avl", "fpm", "electrical", "arch"]` supposed to represent?  It can be done with a plain for -loop. You're probably over thinking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need dynamic variables names. You need variables to dynamically refer to different objects.  You can simply add a another for-loop with arrays to reuse the same code.

Assuming `variableNames` are `sheetNames`,

```
const sheetNames = ['civil', 'struct', 'avl', 'fpm', 'electrical', 'arch'];
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
for (let si = 0; si < sheetNames.length; si++) {
  let thisSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNames[si]);
  let thisData = thisSheet.getRange('A:A').getValues();
  for (let j = 0; j < thisData.length; j++) {
    if (thisData[j][0] == '~Hot List~') {
      let thisHot = j + 3;
    } else if (thisData[j][0] == '~Coordination Items~') {
      let thisCoord = j + 1;
    } else if (thisData[j][0] == '~Responsibilities~') {
      let thisResp = j + 1;
    }
  }
}
```